# How to include send message and inbox option in a Node.js web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, chat

I want to add a send message and inbox option in my node.js application. Basically the website is all about posting jobs in the forum, where three types of people can search and post jobs according to their profiles. Three of them are freelancers, mentors and clients.
So in order to them to communicate with each other, is there any way i can include a chat option in each of their profiles, so that they can send messages to each other.
I have also checked the option of Socket io for chat application, but i am little confused that whether is it a right solution according to my requirement or not.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io will allow for realtime chat communication like gmail's 'gchat', 
so socket.io would be a relevant solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, got that solution.